# How to get nested data from an API with Alamofire?

Tags: swift, parsing, alamofire, swift5, pokeapi

Im using Swift 5, Alamofire and perhaps SwiftyJSON, but idk how to implement it yet.

My main API url is https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151 and contains a "results" element that has an array of objects. Those objects are pokemons, with a name and a url.

The url element of every pokemon object leads to another endpoint, with more information about each pokemon.

This is how those endpoints looks like: https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/

Every pokemon has an "abilities" element, which is an array of two ability objects. I need that data, but can't figure out how to reach it.

**EDIT:** This is how my structs looks like

```
struct Pokemons: Codable {
    let results: [Pokes]?
}

struct Pokes: Codable {
    let name: String?
    let url: String?
}

struct PokePage: Codable {
    
    let abilities: [Ability]?
    let id: Int?
    
    init(abilities: [Ability], id: Int, name: String) {
        self.abilities = abilities
        self.id = id
    }
    
}

struct Ability: Codable {
    let name: String?
    let url: String?
    
    init(name: String, url: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.url = url
    }
}
```

Comment: If you post your JSON (in a nicely formatted way) people will be glad to help you with an object structure suitable for your request. Nowadays nobody should follow a randomly generated URL and most people knowledgable enough to answer your question will refrain to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Your problematic is not related to Alamofire or SwiftyJSON. It is an architure problem.

A basic and naive solution :

1. Fetch your first endpoint
2. Construct your array of Pokemon based on `results`
3. Then for each Pokemon fetch the associated endpoint to get its details

This solution can trigger performance issues. If results returns 10 000 Pokemon you'll trigger 10 001 requests in very short amount of time.

You should consider to trigger the details request when you really need it.

- On scroll if Pokemons are displayed in a list
- In a detailed view when you are about to push it

Comment: Now it says "Expected to decode String but found a dictionary instead." Here's a capture of my code: https://gyazo.com/d254a637f5ff7e07502a8f9c15c14255

Comment: @3rnestocs I don't think your codable models matches the api data types. Post a link to show us how your models/structs look like - I'm sure we'll be able to help you faster.

Comment: Done, I added up the structs on my post